# Update IsInStock attribute in observer by 'catalog_product_save_after' event in Magento2.3

Tags: php, magento2

I have tried this code in Magento 2.3.4

1. created events.xml in Dapl\Shortdurability\etc\adminhtml

2.created Productsaveafter.php in Dapl\Shortdurability\Observer.

```
<?php
namespace Dapl\Shortdurability\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action;
    use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
    {    
    private $action;
    private $stockItemRepository;
   
    public function __construct(
        StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        Action $action
    )
    {
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
     
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct(); 
        $_id = $_product->getId(); // for Id
        $_shortdurability = $_product->getShortdurability();
        $_visibility = $_product->getVisibility();
        $_qty = $this->stockItemRepository->get($_id);
        $quantity = $_qty->getQty();
        if(($_shortdurability == 1) && ($quantity == 0))
        {
            $this->action->updateAttributes([$_id], ['visibility' => 1], 0);
            
        } else {
            $this->action->updateAttributes([$_id], ['visibility' => 4], 0);
            //$this->action->updateAttributes([$_id], ['quantity_and_stock_status' => ['is_in_stock' => 1]], 1);
        }
    }   
}
```

Hi. I can't use save method to set IsInStock attribute value. Because, it's going to infinite loop. finaly i have tried every set method. But stock status has not changed.
i have also tried updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem), updateAttributes([$_id], ['quantity_and_stock_status' => ['is_in_stock' => 1]], 1).
please, help me. I have searched about it from google, still i am not able to update IsInStock attribute of product, in Magento 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using catalog_product_save_after. So on product save you are again saving and again this event called so bottleneck happens. I would suggest using a different event. Or use catalog_product_save_before event and just set the `$_product->setSku("testNew1")`; and not save $product object.

Comment: Yup. This is correct. I have tried this.But I want to update stock status(IsInStock) attribute. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$product->setStockData(['qty' => $yourQty, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $yourQty, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
```